How do I edit a yaml file with python in a way that preserves format, comments, anchors, etc.?
Let's say I have this source yaml file:
top_level: &TL
  field0: somestring
  field1: "this one has quotes"
  field2: [1,2,3]
  # This comment describes something very important about field3
  field3:
    deep_list:
      - name: foo
        field1: bar
        field2: baz
        quoxx: { flow_form: 42, bar: [one, two], field}
        # Here is another super important comment about the blockform field
        blockform:
          - one
          - two
          - three
      - name: bar
        message: I was written by a human
                 and deliberately formatted
                 this way for a good reason.

level0:
  level1:
    level2:
      - item
      - item2: 23
        tl: *TL

And I would like to modify it with a python program. For example, perhaps I want my python program to add a new element to top_level.field3.deep_list. But as you might have noticed from the content of this file, it's important for this modification/update operation preserve the formatting, string quoting conventions, anchors, and comments of the rest of the file. In other words, I want the modification to be minimally invasive: it should only add the new lines necessary to update the list and all other lines should be left completely untouched. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?
Current solution
Based on my research so far, the most viable option seems to be ruamel.yaml which is a yaml serializer/deserializer that is capable of round-tripping a yaml document in such a way that preserves many aspects of the original formatting and comments. However ruamel.yaml is still an imperfect solution for my use case. Although ruamel.yaml gets me way closer to what I want than PyYaml, it seems that it is still not capable of preserving some formatting decisions from the origingl yaml document. For example, from what I understand, ruamel.yaml can't preserve whitespace or line breaking of strings.
So although ruamel.yaml is a somewhat viable option for my use case, I want to know if there is an even better solution out there that can give me what I really want, which is a minimally invasive edit, i.e. an edit operation that ONLY changes the lines directly effected by the data modification and leave all other lines as they exist in the original version verbatim.

You need to provide more context as to what's preventing you from using ruamel.yaml. If you're in a restricted environment where you can't install any 3rd-party library at all, you will certainly have to include your own YAML reader and writer for this (which can be easily done by copying ruamel.yaml's code into your own project (with clear credits given) instead of making it an external dependency).

See this question which explains why this is generally hard and difficult to achieve with implementations that follow the spec. Even ruamel only allows you to keep some formatting, but not all. If you need a serialization format that can properly round-trip, use XML. Or use an automatic code formatter on your YAML, which would solve your problem since everything you do not touch will be formatted as before.

@blhsing I edited the question to further explain the situation regarding ruamel.yaml. In short, it is not disallowed, but I believe it provides an imperfect solution because only some aspects of the original formatting are preserved in the round-trip
